# How do you make a button remove a row with Core Data in an Outline View?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an outline view with 2 entities being displayed inside it so It is connected to a NSTreeController. I have created a button and binded it to the NSTreeController's Controller Key 'canRemove' under Availability>Enabled. But when you run the App the button is always Disabled even when a row is selected in the Outline View. How can this be fixed to work and remove the selected row in the Outline view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the button's target to the tree controller, and its action to `remove:`. This is easy in IB: Right-click on the tree controller, then drag from its `remove:` action (specifically, from the circle at the right edge of the row) to the Remove button.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to do that, Did it now but it still does not work, Here's a screen shot of the bindings and connections for the button, hope it helps solve the problem: http://snapplr.com/qsa5

Comment: What I mean is that the button is disabled and will not allow you to click it.

Answer (score 3):

Is 'editable' enabled on the tree controller?